# Perforce error: File(s) could not be locked

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have some new files I wanted to sync to our Perforce server. I have them in my workspace and Marked for Add. They show up in the changelist. But when I click "Submit", I get "File(s) could be not be locked" and that's that.

As far as I know I have complete user permissions from this machine and admin/super access on my P4 account. Any idea what could cause this? Most of the advice out on the web dates back to pre-2010 Perforce.

I am using P4V if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

This particular message indicates a failure to lock a depot file (on the Perforce side), not a file in your local workspace.  Double-check the log pane to see if there's a more detailed error message there, and failing that, try doing the submit from the command line (p4 submit -c CHANGE).

The two most likely reasons for that error message (and you should get this right under the "files could not be locked" error in the log pane or at the command prompt) are:

1. You don't have "write" permission to one of those files within Perforce
2. Someone else has one of those files locked, preventing other submits

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, but once did a sync of all files  and then tried to re submit , it worked